# Finding order of a point on eliptic curve

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elliptic-curves, ordered-fields

Just started studying eliptic curves and am having trouble with this question. An explanation/solution would be much appreciated.

Find the order of the point X on the elliptic curve $E/Q$ for the two cases:

$X = (0,16)$ on $y^2 = x^3 + 256$

$X = (0.5,0.5)$ on $y^2 = x^3 + 0.25x$

Comment: What do you know about elliptic curves so far? Do you know how the abelian group that is defined over them works? Do you know what the order of an element in a group is?

Comment: Hint: Lutz-Nagell theorem gives you all points of finite order

Comment: @DRF Not sure about the abelian group, but I do know about order of a group

Comment: @LostStudent You really need to find out how an elliptic curve has the structure of an abelian group, because that is what the word 'order' in the problem refers to.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe the group law for an elliptic curve in short form, ie $E: y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ for some $A$, $B$.

The group law on the elliptic curve can be defined geometrically, if $P$, $Q$ are distinct points, then draw the straight line between the two points. This line will intersect the curve with multiplicity $3$ so let $R$ be the third point. Finally if $R=(x,y)$, then reflect in the $x$-axis and take $P+Q=(x,-y)$ and this defines an abelian group. Note here that $R=(x,y)$ is the inverse of $P+Q$, i.e. $(P+Q)+R=O$, where $O$ acts as the identity and is the point at infinity.

There are a couple of exceptions to this:

$1)$ If $P=Q$, then we take the tangent line to the curve instead to find $R$.

$2)$ If either $P=O$ (respectively $Q=O$), we set $P+Q=Q$ (respectively $P$).

$3)$ If $P=(x,y)$ and $Q=(x,-y)$, then the line is vertical and we set $R=P+Q=O$.

**Using this we note that if $P \in E$ has the form $P=(x,0)$ then by point $3)$, $P=-P$, ie $2P=P+P=O$.**

Now let's calculate the order of your points.

Let $E: y^2=x^3+256$, $X=(0,16)$.

We obtain the derivative of the curve which is $2y \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2$ so at $X$, we have $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$ so the tangent line has gradient $0$. Further the tangent passes through $X$ so the equation is $y=16$. Substituting this back into our original equation, we get $16^2=x^3-256$ so $x^3=0$.

The only solutions to this is $x=0$, so our point $R$ is again $X=(0,16)$. Hence $2X=X+X=(0,-16)$ by above. Now notice that $X=-2X$ so in particular $3X=O$ and since $X \neq O$, the order of $X$ must be $3$.

Now your second curve is $E: y^2=x^3+x/4$ with $X=(1/2,1/2)$. Again the derivative of $E$ is $2y \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2+1/4$ so the gradient at $X$ is $1$ and so the equation of the tangent is $y-1/2=x-1/2$, ie $y=x$.

Putting this back into $E$, we get $x^2=x^3+x/4 = x(x-1/2)^2$. Since $X$ has $x$ coordinate $1/2$, $R$ must have $x$ coordinate $0$. Putting this back into our equation for the tangent line $y=x$ we get $R=(0,0)$ and hence $2X=X+X=(0,0)$.

Now we again apply point $3)$, since the $y$-coordinate is $O$ to find that $4X=O$ so $X$ has order at most $4$. However, by our calculations $2X \neq 0$ so it cannot have order $2$ and hence the order equals $4$.